# Compartir proyecto de Visual Studio Code con Live Server y una URL personalizada similar a ngrok

Tags: php, html, css, vscode-live-server

Buen día gente
Recuerdo haber visto un video donde un tipo con la versión más reciente de Visual Studio Code podía replicar lo que hace ngrok, lo que me resulto interesante ya que trabajo en un proyecto y al realizar pruebas tengo que mostrarlas desde la pc y simular el teléfono, alguien tiene mas información al respecto?

Comment: ¿Has intentado ver la documentación oficial? Lo que acabo de hacer fue ir a este link: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Live%20Server&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.1.0&method=topbar y de ahí, encontré el sitio oficial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: que tiene esto que ver con php, html, css ???

Comment: Pues es mas simple y facil usar el ngrok, en todo caso aqui puedes verlo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4jgr0ppw8Q&t=3s

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYLCEONnw2c